# CoreML model undefined symbol error

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, coreml

I've created a coreML model, that when I try to use in my Objective-C project gives me the following error:

`Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_MLFeatureValue", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in logistic_model_8000.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_MLModel", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in logistic_model_8000.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)`

PS: I am not sure about other details that I can add to the question that may help in answering it. If you need more details, please put it in comments.

Comment: Sorry to see the question wasn't resolved. I'm having the same issue. Found a solution in the end?

Comment: same here, already linked CoreML still got this

Answer (score 6):

"Link Binary With Library"

ADD:

CoreML.framework

Comment: Worked for me! I think, it is a pretty simple solution, but somehow it did not work for me after the first try. I had to clean the project several times.

Comment: You missed some libraries to link binary with, for example i was facing this error when i added mlmodel and changed auto generation setting to objective-c then i remember to link Vision.framework + CoreML.framework